# How can I create a double polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three profile types in my Application:

- Employee
- Customer
- Suppliee (supplier's employee)

And I have many different email trackings:

- EmailOpen
- EmailBounce
- EmailClick
- etc.

There is a table for each of them and I would like to make a double polymorphic association such as that a profile can have many different email_activities and, an email_activity belongs_to a profile.

Initially, there was just one single email tracking and thus the polymorphic association looked like this:

```rb
# employee.rb, customer.rb, suppliee.rb

has_many :email_activities, as: :profile
```

```rb
# email_activity.rb
belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true, optional: true
```

Now, however, there are many I would still like each profile to access them using email_activities through a polymorphic association.

The code I have at the moment looks like this:

```rb
# employee.rb, customer.rb, suppliee.rb

has_many :email_activities, polymorphic: true, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

```rb
# email_open.rb, email_bounce.rb, email_click.rb, etc.

belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true, as: :email_activity, optional: true
```

Whenever I try to access the email_activities for a profile, however, I get this error:

```
Unknown key: :polymorphic
```

I would imagine that the syntax I'm using doesn't quite work in this case. How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

`has_many` hasn't `:polymorphic` key, so try this:

```
# employee.rb, customer.rb, suppliee.rb
has_many :email_activities, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy


# email_open.rb, email_bounce.rb, email_click.rb, etc.
belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true, as: :email_activity
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work that way either. Getting other errors -> uninitialized constant Employee::EmailActivity

Comment: @ilrock do you have migrations with polymorphic associations?